# Своя главная и вывод главной блога WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Хочу сделать свою главную страницу для wordpress, с этим проблем нет, эта проблема решается через home.php, wp ставит ее как главную страницу. Но как мне теперь вывести все записи блога на отдельной странице, также как это было бы например в обычном варианте ?

Вот живой пример http://portfoliothemedemo.wordpress.com/

Главная своя, а если нажать в меню на blog, то открывается главная самого блога? Нужно сделать все это на базе самого wordpress, ставит блог в папку и делать главную отдельно не подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А что Вам мешает создать файл шаблона page-blog.php и создать в wordpress страницу с таким именем. В файле шаблона уже прописывать, что Вы хотите там выводить через [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)
Тогда ссылка на блог будет http://ваш_сайт/blog/